# Azure failed to upgrade the database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to upgrade my DB on Azure but I"m getting this error message.  Please help as the service is down.  I'm getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   XXXXXXXXX.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The database 'XXXXXXXX' has reached its size
>   quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the
>   documentation for possible resolutions.

So I tried to upgrade my DB but I'm getting this error

> DESCRIPTION Database scale operation from  Web to S0 Standard failed
>   for . ErrorCode: undefined  ErrorMessage: The edition
>   'Standard' does not support the database max size '20 MB'. STATUS
>   Error TIME Tuesday, January 26, 2016, 11:50:54 AM

Please help.

Comment: What is the TSQL statement that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following article: [Upgrade to Azure SQL Database V12 using the Azure portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-upgrade-server-portal/#upgrade-all-web-and-business-databases)

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from the MS support.

The way to fix this issue is to:

> 1. go to the management portal
> 2. Go to the database, then to the scale tab,
> 3. and then you can set the max size something different than 20MB

Once you do that upgrading should go without problems.

Wish list for next Christmas:  Santa Baby♫  An email goes out to the owner of the DB for administrative issues like exceeding quotas and such.

Comment: you can set alerts in the portal for 2016 Christmas wish : )

Comment: @JosephIdziorek Thank you!  I can do that right now?  There is a feature like that currently?